# C++ programming to read image

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello can someone please guide me with the code for reading an image pixel values using open cv library with c++?

Comment: You should provide more details. Also, you may just want to read the documentation and tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for opencv is at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/STRAWMAN/cpp/index.html, with http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/STRAWMAN/cpp/fast_element_access.html showing multiple ways to access image pixels.